# How to let store all scons build error messages to a file?

Tags: file, dump, scons

I'm using scons to manage a big project with many directories, each time I build the whole thing and scons output a lot of information. I found it very hard to search information from the total output of scons.

I wish to know the scons config/commandLine that helps to dump all errors into a file, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways you could do this:

- Change the build strings (see the manpage and look at CXXCOM)
- Change the spawn command (see the manpage and look at SPAWN)
- You can redirect stderr on the command line

  - `scons 2> errors.log`

If you're seeing a lot of build error messages and it's not stopping you're build then likely your commands errors aren't propagating and causing scons to stop.  (Or you're running -k (keep going)) ?